# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' getting on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-cli

I have installed jenkins on my digitalocean ubuntu server . On " sudo service jenkins restart " is running fine for sometime ,then it is automatically getting stopped .the result i am getting on "sudo service jenkins status" i have attached .And i am facing the "ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' ".

```
Started by user Sidhartha kumar mahato
Building in workspace /webapps/hello_django/jenkins_check
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/(my git repo) # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://gitlab.com/sidhartha_arima/(my git repo)[git error(on buils now)][1]
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url
```

Comment: I see a Jenkins job log. where is the issue with restarting the Jenkins service?

Comment: I would also check the credentials you're using, permissions, etc.

Comment: i have solved the problem by using default workspace of jenkins(e.g /var/lib/jenkins/workspace) .It was the problem with cutom workspace .